# concatenate cell data if value matches column-Line Break separator excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, mailmerge, vba

I want to concatenate cells according to them matching a value in a different column.

Column A has application name, Column B has email address of fulfillment team. I will illustrate the same below :-

[Sample Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxsE4.jpg)

I have seen multiple answers to the same, both through Formula and through VBA. The problem with a formula is that I have to do the same for 5 different columns, not 1, and it will be on a recurring basis ( eventual goal is using mailmerge to send out email as mailmerge does not send multiple rows together, so this is my solution to it )

With VBA, the code is separating the values with a comma and not a line break.

Either solution would work. Any help regarding the same will be appreciated.

Comment: I want to change the separator from comma to a line break. Which the original post you linked this to does not include.

Comment: google line break char: `Chr(10)`

Comment: That would work for simple concatenation, however it does not work in the VBA code. I have been editing the code multiple times, however to no avail. If that is possible I would be grateful for your help.